# convert hexadecimal to decimal in c programming

Tags: c, for-loop

I want to convert from hexadecimal string to decimal number. But my result is different.
This is my code in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
main() {
    char c[100];
    int n,i;
    n=0;
    printf("Enter Your Hexadecimal:\n");
    scanf("%s",c);
    for(i=0; c[i]!='\n' ; i++)
    if(c[i]>='0' && c[i]<='9')　        n=n*16+(c[i]-'0');
    else if(c[i]=='a' || c[i]=='A')     n=n*16+(10);
    else if(c[i]=='b' || c[i]=='B')     n=n*16+(11);
    else if(c[i]=='c' || c[i]=='C')     n=n*16+(12);
    else if(c[i]=='d' || c[i]=='D')     n=n*16+(13);
    else if(c[i]=='e' || c[i]=='E')     n=n*16+(14);
    else if(c[i]=='f' || c[i]=='F')     n=n*16+(15);
    printf("%d",n)
    getch();
}
```

The result is

```
Enter Your Hexadecimal:
2f
-585093843       /* This is the result of my code*/<br>
```

..........Added Answer After Some Times!................

After one year I add the answer of this question for beginners and 
newbies inc`C` Language ...Hope to be useful

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main() {
    char c[100];
    int n,i;
    n=0;
    printf("Enter Your Hexadecimal:\n");
    scanf("%s",&c);
    for(i=0; c[i]!='\n' && c[i]!=0 ; i++){
            if(c[i]>='0' && c[i]<='9')
                n=n*16+(c[i]-'0');
            else if(c[i]=='A' || c[i]=='a')
                n=n*16+(10);
            else if(c[i]=='B' || c[i]=='b')
                n=n*16+(11);
            else if(c[i]=='C' || c[i]=='c')
                n=n*16+(12);
            else if(c[i]=='D' || c[i]=='d')
                n=n*16+(13);
            else if(c[i]=='E' || c[i]=='e')
                n=n*16+(14);
            else if(c[i]=='F' || c[i]=='f')
                n=n*16+(15);
            else{
                printf("Error:Your number Is Not Valid!");
                return -1;
            }       
    }
    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: Ask yourself what `i` is when evaluating `c[i]` in *all* of this code.

Comment: Where is the type of `c`?

Comment: What types of values do you intend to store in the array `c`? Do you think you need to tell the compiler about that?

Comment: change condition `for(i=0; c[i]!='\n' ; i++)` to `for(i=0; c[i]!='\0' ; i++)`

Comment: There are many error in your code you can check it here [how to convert hexadecimal number to decimal number system in C](http://codeforwin.blogspot.in/2015/09/c-program-to-convert-hexadecimal-to-decimal-number-system.html)

Answer (score 2):

Point 1. You never initialized `i`. No type mentioned for `c` [maybe it'll get type default to `int`]

Point 2. You did not use a loop to check all the digits in the input[if it is having more than one digit].

Point 3. You did not check for the success of `scanf()`

Point 4. You never validated the input, neither you did limit the input to one digit [as per current logic].

Point 5. Did not use a proper signature for `main()`, no `return` [more of a good practice point of view]

and *maybe* many more. I'm out.

Comment: Excuse me.I am not well in HTML .I edit my code and put it again

Comment: @Converter I assume it's morning for you:D Your program is written in C not in html.

Comment: @Converter Right, but what `HTML` has to do anything whith this?

Comment: I apologize for my last question that not be write good!my code is in c!

Comment: Is there anyone how answer my question!

Comment: @Converter did you try what Mr.  code frenzy suggested?

Comment: No sir.I am an starter in c with Keringhan Ritchie.I want to know whats my problem in this code.please explain for me.

Comment: @Converter No need to call me sir. Last comment is targeted to point 2 in my answer. FYI, a character array terminated with a `\0` is considered a _string_. So, you've got to loop until you reach `\0`, not `\n`. Am I able to clear your doubt?

Comment: Oh thanks.You are really a SIR........thanks again.But why when i put /n my code don't work????

Comment: @Converter `\n` doesn't work because there's no `\n` in the _scanned_ string. The `\n`, generated by pressing ENTER after your input is left in the input buffer, not a part of the _scanned_ string.

Comment: But. in my program when i enter a hexadecimal and press "enter" key  my result shown.why???

Comment: I think when i press ENTER character "/n" add to my string.Is it wrong??

Comment: @Converter sorry I was away. NO, when you press ENTER, `\n` is not added, rather, `scanf()` appends a `\0` after the inputs. `\n` is entered, but not _scanned in_. It will be left in the input buffer, i.e, it will not be a part of  the scanned value.